# Some tests fail with "the communication channel with asp.net could not be configured" when running auto-generated tests against ASP.NET web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, mstest

The scenario:

- Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET web application
- Create a web service class and give it some `WebMethod`-attributed methods
- Have Visual Studio auto-generate unit tests for the methods, by right-clicking in the class definition and choosing `Create Unit Tests...`
- Note that the generated code for each test includes this boilerplate:

  ```
  // TODO: Ensure that the UrlToTest attribute specifies a URL to an ASP.NET page 
  // (for example, http://.../Default.aspx). This is necessary for the unit test to 
  // be executed on the web server, whether you are testing a page, web service, or 
  // a WCF service.
  [TestMethod]
  [HostType("ASP.NET")]
  [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\...\\ProjectName", "/")]
  [UrlToTest("http://localhost:59733/")]
  public void MethodNameTest()
  ```
- Add in `Default.aspx` to `UrlToTest`, as requested by the comment:

  ```
  [UrlToTest("http://localhost:59733/Default.aspx")]
  ```
- Run all tests in the class

The problem:

Inconsistently, some tests fail with

> **The communication channel with ASP.NET could not be configured. Requested Service not found**

Which tests fail and which tests pass can vary from run to run. There appears to be no pattern to the failures, but it's never the case that all successfully run.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the case that the page you've specified in `UrlToTest` always performs a `Response.Redirect` on load? Because if it is, this will the the cause of the failures you're seeing.

Change the URL specified in `UrlToTest` to that of a page that does **not** perform a `Response.Redirect`, and your tests should run fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run your tests through the Resharper unit test runner. That also gets rid of the problem for me. That also avoids having to reload the web.config multiple times and feels quicker as well.